# How to abtract DBMS requests in a .NET program, while being able to alter database during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I am posting this thread because I didn't find any easy way to abstract my db requests like LinQ does, allowing my program to alter dynamically the database, creating tables or fields.

I am using .NET framework 4.0 and SQL Server 2012, on windows.
I have seen a lot of topics on ORMs such as Entity Framework that allows to run migrations on the db at runtime, only they can't be generated at runtime.

For now, my project creates table at runtime by executing hard-coded SQL Server scripts. 
Only, I dont want to use specifically SQLServer, I want to use some generic language that generates a script for the right DBMS according to my c# code.

---

Example :
I want to alter my data design at runtime because my program is actually running on several machines that have their own database.
When I update the program I would like it to create new tables that are used by the new functionnalities.

Let's say I am adding... a QCM for the user.
I have a winform that allows the user to see the questions and answer it. 
Now to keep track of the answers, I want my program to create a new table using Linq and then fill it with the answers.
If I understand well, when using Entity Framework with code-first approach : 
I would have to use the packet manager console to Add migrations on every machine, before running :

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
migrator.Update();
```

Or is there a way to send to the machine a migration file that will updated with migrator.Update(); ?

Comment: So, you have code that works for SQL Server, but want to expand it to work on any general database?

Comment: LINQ doesn't abstract database requests, it's the underlying **ORM** that does so. Whether LINQ to SQL or LINQ to EF, it's the ORM that provides the abstraction. What do you mean "generated at runtime"? Code-first ORMs like EF, *do* generate or update the database at runtime

Comment: As for targeting different database products, that's one of the key features of all **ORMs**. Targetting a different product is typically a matter of specifying a new connection string and provider. The provider takes care of generating SQL scripts appropriate for each product

Comment: Why do you want to alter your data design at run-time?  Are you also altering your class/OO design at run-time?  If not, then you probably shouldn't alter the data-design either as the two are (supposed to be) linked at a very fundamental level.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited the post after reading your comment

Comment: You probably misunderstood migrations. You don't add one per machine - you add one per schema change/version. When you call `Update()` EF will check the existing migration level and perform only those that came after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do something that is not a good fit for for EF (or virtually any ORM for that matter).  ORM's are generally designed to map a static data model to a static object model.

While it's not impossible to do what you want, it would require a very deep understanding of EF and it's implementation details, to use the lower-level functions as well as Dynamic Linq.  Then you'd have to map this to dynamic C# objects that can change at runtime.

Frankly, you're probably better off writing a custom data layer yourself using standard SQLCommand statements.

As far as migrations go, this is generally a development/deployment tool, not a runtime tool.

Comment: Thank you for that answer I think it is very true

Answer (score 0):

The SqlCommand class in .net allows direct access to the database, including the execution of arbitrary scripts. This will allow you to send any valid database instruction script to the database, including schema definition scripts. This will allow you to create, define, backup, restore and destroy databases.

Comment: And so do all ORMs, that use a DbCommand in the end. That doesn't answer the (admittedly unclear) question

Comment: It would allow the OP to fulfill their requirement to runtime define their schema. As to the level of abstraction - I'd be pedentic and argue that SQL DDL is an abstract language anyway :-)

Comment: You missed the point. What is the actual answer? Every ORM uses ADO.NET. An ORM *generates* a query and executes it with SqlCommand or DbCommand. It also *generates* migration scripts

Comment: I dont think its relevant that ORMs use ADO.net - the correct level of abstraction that the OP needs is to use SqlCommand - an ORM does not have a DDL layer. EF has a design time DDL Generator - but thats a wholly different thing. The migrations it generates are hard coded; not what the OP wants at all. EF is also a code/db mapper - again the OP does not need or benefit from a code/db mapper becuse they wont know their Schema at design time. Their only option is to use SqlCommand because the appropriate abstraction level is the SQL langauge generated at runtime.